# apache2 multiple virtualhost but only first one works

Tags: php, apache, symfony, ubuntu

I am running Apache/2.4.12 on Ubuntu and I added 2 .conf files in the /etc/apache2/sites-available/ folder, and enabled them. Both sites are using the same Symfony PHP files.

aaa.conf

```
Listen 8080
<VirtualHost *:8080>


    ServerName local.aaa.com
    ServerAlias www.local.aaa.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/aaa/web
    <Directory "/var/www/html/aaa/web">
           AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/aaa_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/aaa_access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

bbb.conf

```
Listen 8081
<VirtualHost *:8081>


    ServerName local.bbb.com
    ServerAlias www.local.bbb.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/bbb/web
    <Directory "/var/www/html/bbb/web">
           AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/bbb_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/bbb_access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

The problem I am having is that after a `service apache2 reload` only the first site that I open works. So for example:

**1st scenario**
 - I do the reload
 - I open local.aaa.com:8080 it works
 - I open local.bbb.com:8081 it doesn't work, I get a `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'AppBundle\\AppBundle' not found`

**2nd scenario**
 - I do the reload
 - I open local.bbb.com:8081 it works
 - I open local.aaa.com:8080 it doesn't work, I get a `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'AppBundle\\AppBundle' not found`

**EDIT**
@Ryan Vincent:
`netstat -a` shows both sites runnnig

Comment: why exactly do you need seperate ports, if you are running seperate hostnames anyway ?

Comment: It's part of a bigger project and I need to follow this configuration

Comment: does it work if you where to use the same port for both ?,  also,  are you saying, that after EACH apache reload, the alternating host starts working ?  eit,   maybe there is a third (default) vhost taking over ?

Comment: Changing them to the same port is doing the same thing. Yes after each reload only the first one the I open works, the second no matter which of the 2 produces that error

Comment: silly question, you did enable both vhosts? (a2ensite)

Comment: Yes they are both enabled, they are both working as expected individually, the only problem is running them both together

Comment: is `httpd` actually listed as listening on both of the ports (netstat or equivalent)? Until they are both listened to then it will not work. there may be other issue but we start here. After that it is checking logs, config files and scripts.

Answer (score 0):

All your Listen directives should be in the main apache configuration file provided by Ubuntu(/etc/apache2/apache2.conf).

The sites-enabled folder must only contain the proper symbolic links generated with a2ensite to sites-available, which is where you have to place your virtualhost configurations.

Once you moved them there, enable every virtualhost and reload apache.

```
sudo a2ensite aaa.conf
sudo a2ensite bbb.conf
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Comment: I did the moving and still get the same error when I try to load the 2nd site after the reload. Also it's my bad, I had them in the sites-available but I wrote sites-enabled

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

It has been solved by adding a rule on my firewall (UFW).
The ports i use are 18180 and 18181.
Connexion on port 18180 was OK, but not with 18181.
I tried with UFW disabled, but it didn't work, so i decided to add the rules "allow 18181/tcp" and "allow 18181/udp" and the problem is solved.
It's weird it didn't work with UFW disabled, but it's like that lol

I hope this will help